# Zoom Image and store the visible Image

Tags: iphone

I am working on module where I need to perform following activities.

1. Select image from Library.
2. Show that image.
3. Zoom that image.
4. Save the Zoomed portion or visible portion on the view.so that final image will get saved with zoomed.

I have covered 1,2,3 and struggling with 4

Does anyone have idea about this?

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to save image that appears on the screen after zooming? To do that you can use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect function.